# Wordpress: Get posts by tag, where tag is page slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing Wordpress page template that will get the page slug and use a WP_query to make a list of all posts with tag=page slug. My code doesn't throw up any errors but rather gives me an empty list, when there are definitely posts with the appropriate tag.

Code:

```
<?php
    $tag = $post -> post_name;
    $query = new WP_Query('tag = $tag');
    while ($query -> have_posts()) { 
        $query -> the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>'; 
    }
?>
```

I'm using a local version of Wordpress 4.0.1 on Mac, Yosemite.

Any advice would be much appreciated,

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common mistake (I've done this myself several times.)  In PHP, variables substitution only works with strings that are bound by double quotes.  Single quotes indicate literal strings.  Try this:

```
$query = new WP_Query("tag = $tag");
```

or this:

```
$query = new WP_Query('tag = '.$tag);
```

More info on PHP strings: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks very much! It is now displaying one of three test posts that should show up. Any idea why it would only be showing one?

Comment: Having you tried adding `posts_per_page=-1` to your query?